# Use of Evaluate method results in Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

```
Public Function stockquote(ByRef ticker As String) As Double
    Const Address As String = "XFD1048576"
    Const ViewWorksheet as String = "ViewWorksheet"
    Const xlserviceid As Long = 268435456
    Const xlLanguage As String = "en-US"

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(ViewWorksheet)
        With .Range(Address)
            .ClearContents
            .Value = ticker
            .ConvertToLinkedDataType serviceid:=xlserviceid, _
                LanguageCulture:=xlLanguage
        End With
        
        stockquote = .Evaluate("=" & Address & ".Price")
    End With
    Exit Function
    
ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    stockquote = -1
End Function
```

If the function is run on immediate window, it works fine. But if used in worksheet, it gives "Application-defined or object-defined error" Can someone explain what is wrong with the code

Comment: If you use this as an UDF there are certain [restrictions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1). Among others you cannot use `.ClearContents` or change other cells than the one you use the UDF in.

Comment: Give an example of "ticker" and expected result to verify if it works in my computer.